# Multiple interaction in 1 RenderWindow

Tags: vtk

I have 3 renderers which are shown in 1 Render Window, now I want to pick a point in the first 2 renderer.. So far, the code below only work for `src_renderer`. What should I do so each renderer has its own interaction?

Thanks..[image]

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow> renderWindow =
vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow>::New();
renderWindow->SetSize(1024, 320);
renderWindow->AddRenderer(src_renderer);
renderWindow->AddRenderer(tar_renderer);
renderWindow->AddRenderer(res_renderer);

// An interactor
vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor> renderWindowInteractor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor>::New();
renderWindowInteractor->SetRenderWindow ( renderWindow );

// Set the custom stype to use for interaction.
vtkSmartPointer<MouseInteractorStyle2> src_style = vtkSmartPointer<MouseInteractorStyle2>::New();
vtkSmartPointer<MouseInteractorStyle2> tar_style = vtkSmartPointer<MouseInteractorStyle2>::New();
src_style->SetDefaultRenderer(src_renderer);
tar_style->SetDefaultRenderer(tar_renderer);

renderWindowInteractor->SetInteractorStyle( src_style );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can show multiple renderers within a `RenderWindow` by defining a separate viewport for each renderer, through the method `SetViewport`. That way, you can interact with each renderer. Have a look at [this](https://kitware.github.io/vtk-examples/site/Cxx/Visualization/MultipleViewports/) example, I think it might help you.

Comment: The link is here https://kitware.github.io/vtk-examples/site/Cxx/Visualization/MultipleViewports/

Answer (score 0):

you can add an observer to the interactor object to switch interactor styles. see [here](http://vtk.1045678.n5.nabble.com/VTK5-6-1-One-render-window-multiple-renders-and-auto-interactor-style-solution-td4358940.html).